# Specify the order in which programs stop on Windows Shutdown

Tags: windows, shutdown

I have a set of x programs. On a Windows Shutdown, I need one of the programs to always shut down reliably after another. Is there a way to decide or ensure the order in which programs shut down?

Running a script at shutdown via gpedit.msc only executes after programs have already closed (or are closing). Is there anything I can do?

**Clarification**: This also needs to work when the shutdown is induced through pressing the power button as well as a shutdown using the shutdown.exe. It needs to work on multiple computers.

Comment: If it is only intended for one PC, you can make a shortcut to a script that close the programs and then runs de shutdown process...

Comment: I added clarifications that should answer this.

Comment: During shutdown, Windows just sends a close message to everything running.  If you have a series of apps that are dependent on each other, then they should communicate with each other to work out who should act on the close message in what order.

Comment: The problem is, the only way I know how to do something on close of those apps is if they are window apps, not console apps. I cannot change that, I'm not allowed to add window code, so that is not something I can do. That is why I need an order. The Close Message apparently cannot be caught by console apps.